# QuerySet working in shell but not in Views.py - Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

When executing the following QuerySet in the Django shell (`python manage.py shell`):

```
Employee.objects.filter(restaurant__pk = 1)
```

I get a result back:

```
<QuerySet [<Employee: Joyce McDonnals>]>
```

Please excuse me, because I am new to Django. I am trying to implement this queryset dynamically in my webpage through the PK. The `get_queryset` which I have defined in the views.py is:

```
class EmployeeList(ListView):
    template_name= "Restaurants/employee_list.html"
    model = Employee
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = Employee.objects.filter(pk= restaurant.pk)
        return queryset
```

But this returns the error:

```
NameError at /restaurant/1/employees/
name 'restaurant' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/restaurant/1/employees/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'restaurant' is not defined
```

I have tried some variants for the queryset in my views.py, but I can't seem to get it to work. Could someone help me to define this queryset?

Comment: The problem is not the queryset, but standard Python scoping. Where is the value for `restaurant` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: `restaurant` has been defined in my Employee model as a foreign key to the model `RestaurantFeature`, like so: `restaurant = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantFeature, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question;\ where is the *specific* value you want to filter on coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the queryset, but standard Python scoping. You need to think about where the value for restaurant is supposed to be coming from.

In your case, it is clearly coming from the URL; assuming you have a URL something like this:

```
url(r'^restaurant/(?P<restaurant_id>\d+)/employees/$', ...)
```

named capturing group, that value will be stored in `self.kwargs['restaurant_id']`. So you should use that in the filter.

Note also that you can use `restaurant_id` directly as the field, rather than doing a JOIN

So:

```
queryset = Employee.objects.filter(restaurant_id=self.kwargs['restaurant'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The value for restaurant is indeed coming from the URL. Sorry for not adding this. The url regex which I have is: `url(r'^restaurant/(?P<pk>\d+)/employees/$', EmployeeList.as_view(), name='restaurant_employee')`. I added your code, but this causes the error: `KeyError: 'restaurant'`. Could you explain how this still doesn't resolve my issue?

Comment: Oh I resolved the issue by reading your answer again. i changed the `restaurant` to `pk`! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing restaurant into the get_queryset. Probably it should be like that:

```
   def get_queryset(self):
        self.restaurant = get_object_or_404(Restaurant, name=self.args[0])
        return Emploee.objects.filter(pk=self.restaurant)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
queryset = Employee.objects.filter(restaurant__pk=pk_value)
```

you should pass pk_value here and restaurant field should be foreign key to other table. You can check by passing pk_value = 1 as you are doing in shell.

hope this helps. for more info check django model docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/